# Tracking how many times an image loads and gets clicked

Tags: php, jquery, image

A client asked me to create an image for him, and he wants me to set up a script that will track how many times the image is clicked AND how many times the image is loaded. He wants this displayed for him in the WP dashboard so I don't think I can use the servers access logs. I have never done anything like this, so I turn to the stackoverflow community. :)

Can somebody just point me in the right direction? Thanks a million.

Comment: It will be used on a forum as a signature, preferably PHP or jQuery if possible. It will be used sort of for tracking CTR of a forum sales thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to use to the access logs of your web server (for Apache, the most common one, check: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html). Here every hit (both the link page and the image) is logged, so you can get the information from that.

Most web servers have some tools available that can make this a bit easier than counting by hand (or with grep); just search the web for your web server + log analyzer (e.g. http://awstats.sourceforge.net/ for Apache). If you're not hosting the site yourself, chances are that your web host has pre-installed such a tool for you already.

Comment: The thing is, we are making a product (plugin for WP to be specific) and I will need to display this information in the WP dashboard, so the access logs wouldn't be very useful. I'm thinking more of a simple PHP script that I can do all this with.